# Append new data at endof file qsetting

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qsettings

It is possible to me write configuration file use qt Qsetting. but i want it should write at the bottom of file.

```
QSettings* settings= new QSettings("/home/sidheshwar/Desktop/temp.txt", QSettings::IniFormat);
 settings->setValue("Profiles/"+aaaa,one );
```

how is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSettings` provides a key/value store (partitioned in sections), it has no explicit notion of ordering; you cannot tell it to place some stuff before or after other, it'll write the settings in whatever order it feels appropriate. Think at it as if it was a `QHash` or `std::map` - it efficiently maps keys to values, but doesn't let you set an arbitrary elements order.

If you need this kind of functionality you'll have to implement your own INI file reading/writing class.

Comment: and of the topic , i just saw your user profile  what is answer for `Every morning int, double and size_t wake up and go to buy the newspaper. They read the news together, then int and double check their horoscope; size_t never bothers. Why?`

Comment: Because it has no sign, so it doesn't have any horoscope to check, poor thing :o)  (`size_t` is an unsigned type)